# How to prevent duplicate auto-suggestions import

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

Suppose i have some source code like this

```js
// index.js
import xxx from "./lib/xxx"
export { xxx }
```

```js
// lib/xxx.js
export default function() {}
```

After `tsc` compile will generate two files

```
// index.d.ts
import xxx from "./lib/xxx"
export { xxx }
```

```
// lib/xxx.d.ts
export default function(): void;
```

And then suppose i publish this package and named `ex`, when i install `ex`, using in code will get auto-suggestions of import, but i just need one auto-suggestions of import, Can someone tell me how to do it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably want "internal modules" from Typescript's earlier days, which use the `module` keyword to wrap stuff.  See here: https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/02/07/typescript-internal-vs-external-modules/

From the article:

> Internal modules are really namespaces, which is model that is most
> often applied in the browser. There's a big need for namespaces in a
> web application since everything naturally gets loaded into the window
> scope. The window scope can turn into a massive pile of variables if
> you don't manage your scripts carefully. This is where internal
> modules or namespaces really shine.

Typescript's `module` keyword pre-dates actual ECMAscript modules.

Comment: sry, i tried to read the article and I still don’t know how to deal with this problem, i tried to using sth like `dts-bundle` also not working, also show auto-suggestions twice ... and i don't know how to using tsc to generate `internal modules`, should i write the `dts` by myself instead of `tsc` ?